# Checking for NULL in Java

Tags: java

I am using a Bonded JComboBox.  What I want to know is how do I check if that JComboBox has any items in it or not.

Thank you.

Comment: That's a typo.  I just meant plain JComboBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test if the `JComboxBox` reference is `null`, you can compare it with `null` using the `==` operator. To test if the combo-box contains any items, you can use the instance method [`getItemCount`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getItemCount%28%29), which returns the number of items it contains.

```
JComboxBox box = ...
boolean boxIsNull = (box == null); // answers the title of the question
boolean boxHasItems = (box.getItemCount() > 0);
```